# How to make a leaflet map with the right Marker?

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to make a map with leaflet and the marker should show howboften the coordinate occurs.
There for a make a little example, this one coordinate occurs 230 times.
Is there a way to make that look better?

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
leaflet()%>%
  setView(174.764,-36.877,zoom = 16)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(174.764,-36.877,popup = "Maungawhau,230")#occurs 230 times
```

output looks like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zk44.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbwC.png[image]

**Edit**
this one looks nice
[image]

Comment: What is the exact question? The formatting of the popup?

Comment: Is there a way to show the number 230 visually better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addCircleMarker` and make the radius of the circle bigger.
I used sqrt because a radius of 230 is really big but you can do as you prefer.
You can put html code in the popup argument, so you can display the number 230 as you wish.

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
leaflet()%>%
  setView(174.764,-36.877,zoom = 16)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addCircleMarkers(174.764,-36.877,popup = "Maungawhau,<h2><font color=\"red\"><b>230<b></font></h2>",radius=sqrt(230))
```

Update : if you prefer adding labels and not popups you can do something like that :

```
leaflet()%>%
  setView(174.764,-36.877,zoom = 16)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addCircleMarkers(174.764,-36.877,
                   label="230",labelOptions = labelOptions(offset=c(10,0),noHide = TRUE,textOnly=TRUE, textsize="15px",
                   style = list("color" = "red")),
                  radius=sqrt(230))#occurs 230 times
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. 
Is there a way to show the number 230 visually better?

Comment: Just saw your edit in initial post, I added a solution with labels, not pretty as is but you should have everything to customize it the way you want